# Is there an operator meaning ??= in PHP?

Tags: php-7, null-coalescing-operator

Since PHP7, the [null coalescent operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (`$a ?? $b`) means `isset($a) ? $a : $b`.

In my code, I often have facultative variables passed from the controller to the view and I need to set default values in the view if that variable isn't passed.

I would like something like this: `$someVar ??= 42` (not working) that would mean `$someVar = $someVar ?? 42`.

Is there such a shortcut to do that or do I have to stick to the long version? (Yeah, I know, it's not that long, but lazy people will be lazy).

Comment: Looking for the same thing. It comes up so often!

Comment: Yeah, if PHP devs read this question, it might give them ideas :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! [This exists in PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.other) now.

Answer (score 1):

No. No such shortcut.

All PHP operators are linked from this page: [Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). And the details of null coalescing are on this one (not in the initial list, for some reason): [Comparison Operators>Null Coalescing Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce).

Comment: FYI - This is coming in PHP 7.4 - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator